# Is Elementary OS designed for Mac keyboards?

Tags: keyboard

Hey there I would like to get into the Linux world and Elementary OS looks very nice. Currently I'm using Windows and would like to leave it.

When I read some information from the homepage I always see the Mac keyboard icons but never Windows keyboard icons. This image for example

[image]

I got to know that I can use Tweaks to change the windows layout from Elementary to Mac, Windows or other ones but what about the keyboard? By that I mean when pressing the windows key for example it will open the applications menu. Is Elementary OS the right thing for me as a Windows keyboard user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

elementary OS uses the command key found on Mac keyboards to represent the superkey (Which is usually represented as the "windows key" on most keyboards.)

So it's fine. You won't have any problems.

Comment: well let's go for it then :)